# MODIS MCD18A2 (PAR) reproject via rasterio vs. via HDF-EOS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, satellite, raster-conversion

---

I downloaded MODIS L3 PAR data (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/750/MCD18_User_Guide_V61.pdf, https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//DP128/MOTA/MCD18A2.061/2014.07.04/MCD18A2.A2014185.h18v04.061.2021258072101.hdf) and used the HDF-EOS (http://hdfeos.org/) software to can convert the HDFs to GeoTIFFs and reproject to WGS84.

### Settings used in HDF-EOS:

- Output File Type: GeoTIFF
- Resampling: Bilinear
- Projection: Geographic (WGS84)

### Python

I wanted to see if this can also be done with `rasterio` in Python (3.8). I experimented with many different projections. The best match so far comes from this definition:https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6974/proj4/.

### Results

`rasterio` transform': Affine(0.008993206033379587, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, -0.008993206033379587, 49.999999995506855) with resolution @ 1000 m

`rasterio` 'transform': Affine(0.008363681597124058, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, -0.008363681597124058, 49.999999995506855) with resolution @ 930 m

HDF-EOS: transform': Affine(0.008333333332583237, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, -0.008333333332583237, 49.99999999550685) with resolution @ 930 m

I noticed that the effective pixel resolution is not identical between `rasterio` and HDF-EOS. And in consequence, the raster width and height are slightly different.
The target resolution is calculated based on the dataset documentation pdf, where they state a resolution of 1 km. Interestingly the HDF-EOS tool indicates a different resolution of 930 m! If I set the resolution to 930 m instead of 1000 m I come even closer to the HDF-EOS output, but unfortunately, it's still not a perfect match.
Do you have any idea as to what could have gone wrong?

### Code

```py
import rasterio
import rasterio.warp
import numpy
import pyproj

modis_resolution = 1000 # or 930 [m]

with rasterio.open("../data/MCD18A2.A2014185.h18v04.061.2021258072101.hdf") as hdf:
    
    datasets = [name for name in hdf.subdatasets if name.endswith("_PAR")]
    
    for i, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
        # Read individual layers
        print(f"Reading layer {dataset}.")
        if i == 0:
            with rasterio.open(dataset) as src:
                bounds = src.bounds
                src_meta = src.meta.copy()
                src_data = numpy.empty((len(datasets), src_meta["width"], src_meta["height"]))
                src_data[i,:,:] = src.read(1)
        else:
            with rasterio.open(dataset) as src:
                src_data[i,:,:] = src.read(1)
            
        filename = dataset.split(":")[2].split(".hdf")[0] + f"wgs84_bilinear_{modis_resolution}m_SR-ORG-6974.tif"
        
    # https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6974/proj4/
    src_crs = rasterio.crs.CRS.from_user_input(pyproj.CRS.from_proj4("+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
    src_meta.update({"crs":src_crs})
    dst_meta = src_meta.copy()
    dst_meta.update({
        "crs":"EPSG:4326",
        "count":src_data.shape[0]
    })
    
    left, bottom, right, top = bounds
    resolution = rasterio.warp.transform(src_meta["crs"], dst_meta["crs"], [modis_resolution], [modis_resolution])[0][0]

    dst_transform, dst_width, dst_height = rasterio.warp.calculate_default_transform(
        src_crs=src_meta["crs"], 
        dst_crs=dst_meta["crs"], 
        width=src_meta["width"],
        height=src_meta["height"],
        left=left,
        bottom=bottom,
        right=right,
        top=top,
        resolution=resolution
    )
    dst_meta.update({
        "driver":"GTiff", 
        "width":dst_width,
        "height":dst_height,
        "transform":dst_transform
    })
    
    dst_data = src_data.copy()
    for i in range(dst_meta["count"]):
        rasterio.warp.reproject(
            source=src_data[i,:,:],
            destination=dst_data[i,:,:],
            src_transform=src_meta["transform"],
            src_crs=src_meta["crs"],
            dst_crs=dst_meta["crs"],
            resampling=rasterio.warp.Resampling.bilinear, 
            src_nodata=src_meta["nodata"],
            dst_nodata=dst_meta["nodata"]
        )
            
    with rasterio.open(filename, mode="w", **dst_meta) as dest:
        for i in range(1, dst_meta["count"]+1):
            dest.write(dst_data[i-1,:,:], i)
```